# Как отключить function Js localStorage

Tags: javascript, html

Столкнулся с такой проблемой не могу отключить function по нажатию кнопки в function прописана система звука по нажатию.
По умолчанию звук должен быть включен.

Значение False сохраняется в localStorage, что бы когда пользователь перезагрузит страницу у него сохранялись настройки.

Что мы имеем

```
let settings_sound = localStorage.getItem('settings_sound') || true;
```

Код звука при нажатии кнопки

```
function clicksound(){
    if (settings_sound = true) {
        var audio = document.createElement('audio');
        audio.src = 'sound/clickmenu.mp3'
        audio.autoplay = true;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Систему которая присваивает False чтобы отключить функцию

```
const clicksBTsoundOff = () => {
    if (settings_sound = true) {
        settings_sound = false
        updateStorageSetSound(settings_sound);
    }
}

function updateStorageSetSound(settings_sound) {
    localStorage.setItem('settings_sound', settings_sound);
}

document.getElementById('sound_off').addEventListener('click', clicksBTsoundOff)
```

Пробовал вывести за предел clicksBTsoundOff

```
updateStorageSetSound(settings_sound);
```

Что бы шла запись в localStorage, что значение settings_sound = True.
Когда нажать на кнопку что бы отключить звук, значение в localStorage меняется на False. Но звук остается и даже если перезагрузить страницу значение все равно будет False и будет звук.

Comment: `if (settings_sound = true) {` вы присваиваете переменной true,... для проверки нужно `if (settings_sound === true) {` в обеих местах

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибки у вас в сравнениях:

```
 if (settings_sound = true) { // = - оператор присваивания, а не сравнения
```

Должно быть:

```
 if (settings_sound === true) { // === - оператор сравнения
```

Вообще можно просто оставить так:

```js
 if (settings_sound) {
```

Метод `Storage.getItem()` возвращает `string` или `null`, поэтому нужно привести результат к типу `boolean`

Вместо такого выражения:

```
let settings_sound = localStorage.getItem('settings_sound') || true;
```

Можно использовать что-то такое:

```
let settings_sound = (localStorage.getItem('settings_sound') || 'true') === 'true';
```

Зачем каждым кликом создавать новый элемент `<audio>` чтобы единоразово воспроизвести звук? У вас так DOM забьется мусором. Можно же один раз создать и уже сколько угодно раз воспроизводить звук с помощью этого элемента.

Сделайте лучше как-то так:

```js
let settings_sound = (localStorage.getItem('settings_sound') || 'true') == 'true'; // всегда вернет boolean

const audio = new Audio('sound/clickmenu.mp3'); // создаем HTMLAudioElement
document.append(audio); // добавляем HTMLAudioElement в document

function clicksound () {
    if (!settings_sound) return; // если звук отключем, завершаем выполнение функции, возвращаем void 
    audio.play(); // иначе проигрываем аудио
}

function clicksBTsoundOff() {
    if (!settings_sound) return; // если settings_sound false, возвращаем void
    settings_sound = false;
    updateStorageSetSound(settings_sound);
}

function updateStorageSetSound(settings_sound) {
    localStorage.setItem('settings_sound', settings_sound); // boolean будет приведен к типу string
}
```

Ознакомьтесь дополнительно с материалом:

- [Audio()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement/Audio)
- [Выражения и операторы](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators)
- [Storage.getItem()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem)

Comment: Спасибо за расширенный ответ, с материалами обязательно ознакомлюсь.